# jmeter- what i need to do extra to connect with mysql database?

Tags: jmeter

In my JMeter test-plan, I created a thread group and added config element with JDBC connection configuration:

```
Url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atmdb,
Driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
username: ****
password: ****
```

I also added jdbc request sampler and a view result tree listener. However after executing this test plan, I saw this error:

```
2015/12/18 12:53:39 INFO - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2015/12/18 12:53:39 INFO - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2015/12/18 12:53:39 WARN - jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement: Could not load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) 
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) 
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) 
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) 
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) 
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270) 
  at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.datasource.ResourceLimitingJdbcDataSource.configure(ResourceLimitingJdbcDataSource.java:264) 
  at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.initPool(DataSourceElement.java:235) 
  at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.testStarted(DataSourceElement.java:108) 
  at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:214) 
  at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:336) 
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015/12/18 12:53:39 INFO - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,local) 
2015/12/18 12:53:39 INFO - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : JDBC Users 
2015/12/18 12:53:39 INFO - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group JDBC Users. 
2015/12/18 12:53:39 INFO - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2015/12/18 12:53:39 INFO - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2015/12/18 12:53:39 INFO - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2015/12/18 12:53:39 INFO - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2015/12/18 12:53:39 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: JDBC Users 1-1 
2015/12/18 12:53:39 WARN - jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement: Could not return Connection java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atmdb at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596) 
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215) 
  at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.datasource.JdbcConnectionFactory.newInstance(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:182) 
  at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.InstrumentedResourceLimitingPool.newPoolable(InstrumentedResourceLimitingPool.java:655) 
  at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.newPoolable(ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.java:145) 
  at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.datasource.ResourceLimitingJdbcConnectionPool.newPoolable(ResourceLimitingJdbcConnectionPool.java:91) 
  at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.InstrumentedResourceLimitingPool.get(InstrumentedResourceLimitingPool.java:371) 
  at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.get(ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.java:97) 
  at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.datasource.ResourceLimitingJdbcDataSource.getConnection(ResourceLimitingJdbcDataSource.java:188) 
  at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement$DataSourceComponentImpl.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:286) 
  at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:146) 
  at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler.sample(JDBCSampler.java:85) 
  at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434) 
  at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261) 
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015/12/18 12:53:39 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: JDBC Users 1-1 
2015/12/18 12:53:39 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: JDBC Users 1-1 
2015/12/18 12:53:39 INFO - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2015/12/18 12:53:39 INFO - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,local)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Follow the below two steps to resolve the issue. It resolved mine

1. Place the mysql connector jar inside apache-jmeter-3.0\lib folder
2. Restart the jmeter

After restart only it will pick the newly placed jar files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not placed correct mysql-connector file in JMeter's Lib folder. Please download this jar file and place it in Lib folder of your JMeter installation.

You can download latest **mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar** from following URL: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html

To properly configure MySQL JDBC connection refer to official JMeter documentation: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration

Comment: thanks for your quick response.....i did exactly what you said but it's not working.

Comment: myqsql-connector also needs to be compatible with mysql db that is being used. So, you need to check which variant/version of mysql you are trying to connect with. Then search for the connector compatible with your db.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's better to have JMeter and MySQL server on separate machines in order to get more reliable results as they can interfere and fight for machine resources.
2. [Download MySQL JDBC Driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and drop it to JMeter's classpath (usually /lib folder of your JMeter installation). Alternatively you can configure the path on [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level

   [image: Add extra jar]
3. If you copy .jar file to /lib folder - restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
4. I would also recommend checking out [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) guide to learn how to perform correlation, add assertions, etc.